# Changing column properties size

Tags: mysql-workbench

How to change column properties size so as to columns list was expand?
[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

You can make the entire pane larger which will then proportionally make the subpage bigger. Additionally, there's a splitter between the column list and the details pane which allows to change the relative size of both parts.